# Creating Dictionary from nth list items

Tags: list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list in which each item in the list is further split into 3 fields, separated by a '| '
Suppose my list is :
[‘North America | 23 | United States’, ’South America | 12 | Brazil’, 
‘Europe | 51 | Greece’………] and so on

Using this list, I want to create a dictionary that would make the first field in each item the value, and the second field in each item the key.

How can I add these list items to a dictionary using a for loop?

My expected outcome would be 
{’23’:’North America’, ’12’:’South America’, ’51’:’Europe’}

Comment: please mention programming language you use

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```cs
var myList = new List<string>() { "North America | 23 | United States", "South America | 12 | Brazil", "Europe | 51 | Greece" };
var myDict = myList.Select(x => x.Split('|')).ToDictionary(a => a[1], a => a[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in Python, if you know what the delimiter is, you can use string.split() to break the string up into a list then go from there.

```
my_dict = {}
for val in my_list:
    words = val.split(" | ")
    my_dict[words[1]] = words[0]
```

For other languages, you can take an index of the first "|", substring from the beginning to give you your value, then take the index of the second line to give you the key. In Java this would look like:

```
Map<String, String> myDict = new DopeDataStructure<String, String>();
for(String s : myArray){
    int pos = s.indexOf("|");
    String val = s.substring(0, pos - 1);
    String rest = s.substring(pos + 2);
    String key = rest.substring(0, rest.indexOf("|") - 1);
    myDict.put(key, val);
}
```

EDIT: there very well could be more efficient ways of solving the problem in other languages, that's just the simplest method I know off the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

Using Python dict comphrehension

```
data = ['North America | 23 | United States', 'South America | 12 | Brazil',]
# Spliting each string in list by "|" and setting its 1st index value to dict key and 0th index value to dict value
res = {i.split(" | ")[1]: i.split(" | ")[0] for i in data}
print (res)
```

I hope this helps and counts!